# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf rowspan fail when start new page

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I'm working in Laravel project and I just trying to export table with many rows and some rows have rowspan attribute.

It just work fine whenever the row doesn't exceed to new page.

If it exceed to new page, it break the layout as show in image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOHJz.png)

Can anyone suggest me how I can fix this?